# Run cron job every minute during specific hour during 30 minutes

Tags: cron

I know I can set up cron for every minute, like

```
* * * * *
```

for once a day AFAIK it would be (lets say on 2am)

```
0 2 * * *
```

for every 30 minutes

```
0,30 * * * *
```

Now, is it possible to run cron job every minute, but during 30 minutes, once a day. For example I need the cron to run every day from 2am to 2:30, and during that time every minute.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure. Use this:

```
0-30 2 * * *
^^^^ ^
 |   |
 |   on hour 2
on minutes from 0 to 30
```

Remember the format is as follows:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

Comment: one small qsn, if I need to make during that 30 minutes, not every minute but once per 2 minutes, is there an easy way ? or I should do like `0,2,4,6` and so on up to 30 ? I thought this would work `0-30/2`, but it does not. thanks

Comment: It should work, strange it is not. I just tried a `30-59/2 * * * * touch /tmp/aaa` and `0-29/2 * * * * touch /tmp/bbb` and both worked to me.

Comment: Actually I tried this in shared hosting's cpanel, when I put `0-30/2` in minute field, it showed error `Cron field not formatted correctly.`, here is the screen https://www.openmerchantaccount.com/img/cpanel_cronjob_error.PNG , so I made a conclusion it is not gonna work that way. Then I guess it is some kind of bug in cpanel. thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Oh it is a pity then. As I don't have any cpanel around, I googled a little and could not find any apparent solution. You can try `(0-30)/2`, but I doubt it will work. Good luck with it!